# Reducing casting clutter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, casting

When programming generic classes, I end up with methods cluttered with casts (otherwise I get warnings, which are treated as errors for our projects):

```
template <typename floatType>
class foo
{
public:
  typedef floatType real_type;

  real_type bar()
  {
    real_type a = (real_type)0.5; // should I be using static_cast? Either way, the code becomes cluttered quickly
    real_type b = a + 0.6; // warning here for floatType = float

    real_type someLongEquation = a + ((real_type)0.5 * (real_type)100) + (real_type)17.0;

    return a + b + someLongEquation;
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    foo<float> z;
    z.bar();
  }

  {
    foo<double> z;
    z.bar();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Is there any way to reduce that clutter?**

<sub>Note that I realize I am using magic constants in the `someLongEquation`. Even if I separate them out, there is increased clutter. Either way, that is not the point of the question :)</sub>

Comment: what are the warnings you get?

Comment: @DavidBrown: `Conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data` (pretty standard for casts between built-in types that may results in loss of precision)

Comment: Just put `f` after each constant value. Assigning float to double is okay ;)

Comment: @Rob: MSVC (the warning gives that away if you've been using MSVC).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to just turn off the warning around the code. With MSVC:

```
#pragma warning(push) // save warnings state
#pragma warning(disable:4244) // narrowing conversion
// code here ...
#pragma warning(pop) // restore warnings
```

The better way, however, would be to just use `float` literals if you don't need the extended precision of `double` for your magic constants. Just append an `f` to your floating point literals and you'll be fine. Also, no cast needed for the `100`. If you do in fact need the precision, well, fall back to disabling the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the magic constants out and store them in the right generic type. All the casting will be limited to that location. Now that (I think) C++11 allows in class initialization of non-integral const statics it's easy.

```
template <typename floatType>
class foo
{
public:
  typedef floatType real_type;

  static constexpr real_type A = real_type(0.5);
  static constexpr real_type B = real_type(0.6);
  static constexpr real_type C = real_type(100.0);
  static constexpr real_type D = real_type(17.0);

  real_type bar()
  {
    real_type a = A;
    real_type b = a + B;

    real_type someLongEquation = a + (A * C) + D;

    return a + b + someLongEquation;
  }
};
```

Comment: IIRC, C++11 only allows that for non-static members.

Comment: @Xeo I wasn't able to find the references before, but now I have. static constexpr data members can be initialized in-class if they have 'literal type', which includes `float`. [class.static.data] §9.4.2/3

Comment: Ah, yeah, I overlooked the `constexpr` somehow. :)